# Problemas com angular-input-masks?

Tags: html, angularjs, mask

Estou tentando utilizar esse módulo que está disponível no [github](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks) e acho que esse módulo é muito completo, disponibiliza as máscaras que preciso, no entanto é muito confuso a sua documentação.

A questão é a seguinte, clonei o projeto do gihub e fui executar a pasta [demo](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks/tree/master/demo), nas linhas de código do arquivo [index](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks/blob/master/demo/index.html) (***linhas 8 e 9***), ele faz referencias aos arquivos `Javascript` que deveriam está no repositório, mas não estão, simplesmente não existem, mas não precisa se apavorar, achei todos os arquivos [neste link](http://www.applebees.com.br/scripts/fim-de-ano/angular-input-masks/).

Ao fazer as referencias, ligando os arquivos `Javascript`aos `HTML`, tudo certinho, era para funcionar o [demo], no entanto o mesmo apresenta alguns erros, como por exemplo:

> [image: Erro que apresenta no console]

sendo que dentro do arquivo [angular-input-masks-dependencies.js](http://www.applebees.com.br/scripts/fim-de-ano/angular-input-masks/angular-input-masks-dependencies.js) existe o camarada do ***erro***:

```
function min () 
{
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return pickBy('isBefore', args);
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a usar esse módulo sem erros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para funcionar corretamente utilize esse endereço:

> `https://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/javascripts/masks.js`

que já é o arquivo com tudo que precisa para executar essas mascaras no [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ui.utils.masks'])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.phoneNumber = "";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.6.6/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="https://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/javascripts/masks.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="ctrl">
<h4>ui-number-mask</h4>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="number1" ui-number-mask ui-number-min="0">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="field2" ng-model="number2" ui-number-mask="3" ui-number-min="0">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="field3" ng-model="number3" ui-number-mask="4" ui-negative-number ui-number-min="0">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="field4" ng-model="number4" ui-number-mask ui-number-min-max="100.9" ui-number-min="10.1"></p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="field5" ng-model="number" ui-number-mask ui-hide-group-sep>
  </p>

<h4>ui-br-phone-number</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="field10" ng-model="phoneNumber" ui-br-phone-number></p>

<h4>ui-br-cep-mask</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="field11" ng-model="cep" ui-br-cep-mask></p>

<h4>ui-br-cpf-mask</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="field12" ng-model="initializedCpf" ui-br-cpf-mask></p>

<h4>ui-br-cnpj-mask</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="field13" ng-model="initializedCnpj" ui-br-cnpj-mask></p>

<h4>ui-br-cpfcnpj-mask</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="field14" ng-model="initializedCpfCnpj1" ui-br-cpfcnpj-mask></p>

<h4>ui-br-ie-mask</h4>
<p>
<select ng-init="ufs=['AC','AL','AM','TO']" ng-model="selectedUF" ng-options="uf for uf in ufs"></select>
<input type="text" name="field19" ng-model="ieField" ui-br-ie-mask='selectedUF'></p>

</div>
```

Comment: pensei que só iria concertar os meus erros de português, mas não, resolveu o problema por completo. Só foi preciso lincar o JS correto, masks.js