# Mascara angular-input-masks no AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, mask, input-mask

Estou tentando utilizar a mascara angular-input-masks no AngularJs (ionic v1) que se encontra no link:

https://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/

Sigo todas as etapas que esta na documentação:

https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks

mas acontecem os seguintes problemas, quando tento importar no meu index.html o script:

```
<script src="angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
```

é exibido o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

então, continuo as etapas que estão no manual, "adicionar o ui.utils.masks ao modulo" com o seguinte script:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.utils.masks']);
```

Mas o seguinte erro é exibido:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom, fiz varias buscas e encontrei um post aqui com o mesmo problema:
[Problemas com angular-input-masks?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235409/problemas-com-angular-input-masks)
mas a solução não resolveu para mim é exibido erro 404 no get, irei postar o meu código app.js onde importo todos os módulos e o meu index.html.

```js
// Ionic Starter App

angular.module('starter', ['ionic',
'starter.services',
'starter.controllers',
'starter.pagamento',
'starter.calculadora',
'starter.adicionar-itens',
'ui.utils.masks'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.Keyboard) {
      window.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }

    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.calculadora', {
    url: '/calculadora',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/calculadora.html',
        controller: 'CalculadoraCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  
  .state('app.adicionar-itens', {
    url: '/adicionar-itens',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/adicionar-itens.html',
        controller: 'AdicionarItensCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  
  .state('app.pagamento', {
    url: '/pagamento',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/pagamento.html',
        controller: 'PagamentoCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/adicionar-itens');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/calculadora.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/pagamento.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/alertaPopup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/adicionar-itens.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <script src="lib/snet-barcode.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/alerta_popup.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/javascripts/masks.js"></script> -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pagamento.js"></script>
    <script src="js/calculadora.js"></script>
    <script src="js/adicionar-itens.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    <div id="alerta_popup" class="alerta_popup alerta_popup__delete">
      Alerta
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tambem tentei de todas as formas executar, mas pelo que verifiquei os arquivos contidos no git e no NPM estão incompletos.